# what is meant by open addressing in collision handling?

Tags: data-structures

Collision is occur in hashing, there are different types of collision avoidance.
1)chaining
2)open addressing etc.,
what is meant by open addressing and how to store index in open addressing. calculation??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Collision` is a situation when the resultant hashes for two or more  data elements in the data set U, maps to the `same` location in the hash table, is called a hash collision. In such a situation two or more data elements would qualify to be stored/mapped to the same `location` in the hash table.

`Open addressing` also called `closed hashing` is a method of resolving collisions by `probing`, or searching through alternate locations in the array until either the target record is found, or an unused array slot is found, which indicates that there is no such key in the table.

In open addressing, while inserting, if a collision occurs, **alternative cells** are tried until an `empty` bucket is found. For which one of the following technique is adopted.
There are many ways of probing: `Linear`, `Quadratic`, `Cuckoo hashing` (which I have used in my project), `double hashing`.

Now going into deep what do you mean by `probing`. Suppose we want to do insert and search operation in our hashtable.

*Insert*:

When there is a collision we just probe or go to the next slot in the table. 
If it is `unoccupied` – we `store` the key there. 
If it is `occupied` – we `continue` probing the next slot.

*Search*:

If the key hashes to a position that is occupied and there is no match, 
we probe the next position.

a) `match` – `successful` search

b) `empty` position – `unsuccessful` search

c) `occupied` and `no` match – `continue` probing.

When the end of the table is reached, the probing continues from the `beginning`, 
until the original starting position is reached.

To add more in this, in `open addressing` we **do not** require additional data structure to hold the data as in case of `closed addressing` data is stored into a linked list whose head pointer is referenced through a pointer whose index is stored in our hashtable.

Index is calculated using hash function for each key. Lets say in **linear probing** we need to do insert in a hashtable[20].

```
Hashtablesize=20;

void insert(string s)
{
    // Compute the index using the Hash Function
    int index = hashFunc(s);
    // Search for an unused slot and if the index will exceed the hashTableSize
    // we will roll back
    while(hashTable[index] != "")
        index = (index + 1) % hashTableSize;
    hashTable[index] = s;
}
```

Quadratic probing is also similar to linear one, the difference is in iterating by the probing sequence. In quadratic probing the probing sequence can be

```
index = index % hashTableSize
index = (index + 1^2) % hashTableSize
index = (index + 2^2) % hashTableSize
index = (index + 3^2) % hashTableSize
```

Comment: can you post calculation to store index in open addressing?

Comment: Index is calculated using hash function for the particular key. Example in linear probing,index can be calculated like index = index % hashTableSize

Comment: can i use below one for open addressing If slot hash(x) % S is full, then we try (hash(x) + 1) % S
If (hash(x) + 1) % S is also full, then we try (hash(x) + 2) % S

Comment: can i use below one for open addressing  hashing....                                                     If slot hash(x) % S is full, then we try (hash(x) + 1) % S
If (hash(x) + 1) % S is also full, then we try (hash(x) + 2) % S

Comment: If you found my answer useful, you can accept it as it will help others in future.